# Play button not available for Scheduled Master branch for Developer role in git lab runner

Tags: pipeline, scheduler, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a “Developer” role and I couldn't see Play button if I scheduled job for master branch. Whereas for other sprint branches, play button is visible. Is the role need to upgrade? Can some one help me to understand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order for a scheduled pipeline to be created successfully:

- The schedule owner must have permissions to merge into the target branch.
- The pipeline configuration must be valid.

Otherwise the pipeline is not created.

Source: /help/ci/pipelines/schedules

Make sure the schedule owner has permission to merge to the target branch. e.g under “protected branches”